# 2-d chess board recognition

Tags: android, opencv, chess

I'm trying to develop an Android app that reads a 2-d chess image and recognize the position
(rows are numbered by 1 to 8 and columns a to h ) then:

1. Which square the piece occupied?
2. What piece it is (king or queen or knight etc)
3. Color of piece (black or white)

Need some ideas using openCV or any.

Comment: if you can't help with all of the problems, then pls give ideas/solution for any one

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't really a place for ideas, its more a place for assisting with a specific problem that you've run into, and offering solutions you've tried and failed with, example code and error messages is a good start. You've identified openCV, but what have you done so far?

Comment: can you provide example of picture?

Comment: Recognizing the piece is going to be hard.

Comment: @Hammer, don't have to be, it actually quite a lot depends on picture

Comment: @biddulph.r i identified chess board and the pieces in it by using edge detection but stuck where i've to split image into 64 block and identify object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a part about camera calibration in the book Opencv 2 Computer Vision Application Programming Cookbook. There they use a chess board. Maybe it can help you, solving your problem.

http://www.bol.com/nl/p/opencv-2-computer-vision-application-programming-cookbook/1001004011498107/

Comment: You can also take a look at a paper published in 2016 where the authors solve the exact same problems you are posing https://vision.fe.uni-lj.si/cvww2016/proceedings/papers/21.pdf The authors, however, implemented their tracking system using Matlab.